Can't choose a custom picklist for Log a Call result
In my production Org, in the setup window of Log a Call I'm unable to choose if I want to use Default values or a custom picklist

While in my Sandbox Org I can choose what I want to use

Is there any setting that I'm missing? I added the custom picklist to the Global Action Layout, and his FLS is visible for all profiles

Solved - There's is a bug with the Italian Language, it only works in English
